# How to change tableViewCell background color

Tags: iphone, uitableview

**NOTE:** this is about a **cell in GROUPED tableView**. That makes a HUGE difference, when compared to normal tableView! The default cell customization answers do NOT work in this case, so please verify your answer first.

This is how I set **gray screen** and **yellow tableView** background:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:magicRect];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.tableView addSubview:myView];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:myView];
}
```

This is how I set **green cell** background. As you can see from picture, it's missing some areas:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell =
   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
     reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }
 // Configure the cell...
}
```

**Question:** how can I **change color at start and end of tableView cell**? Now the cell is transparent in those areas and displays self.view.backgroundColor from below the whole tableView. Those areas really are transparent, since textured background remains in same location, when scrolling tableView.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please don't approve [such a too minor suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1364573). Will remove the comment after your response :)

Comment: Any edit that improves readability is something that I'm happy to approve. Checked the case, would approved it again. Sorry about that, readability and simplicity are important for me... btw any tips for THIS question? :)

Answer (score 0):

set tableView Background as clear color like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//Here you can give as yellow instead of adding view
     //ur code
}
```

Comment: Sorry, want to keep that gray background color, too. The idea is to have separate colors for tableView area and area outside tableView. This code overwrites the gray background.

Comment: YOu keep self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; as it is and make tableView's background as yellow

Comment: When using grouped tableView, the tableView backgroundColor overwrites view backgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you add subview to tableview, you can set the background color for tableview:

```
tview.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: Because I want different colors for tableView and area outside tableView. This is a GROUPED tableView, which does not behave in same way as normal tableView.